# How to configure django restframework swagger base path

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I need to set up swagger UI for my Django restframework apis on development server.
I use Django rest swagger and added it to the installed apps in the settings
 the project is deployed using apache2 and the url is `user41.dc/django/`

and so my APIs `usr41.dc/django/api/`..

but the Swagger UI sends the requests to `usr41.dc/api/` skipping the `'/django'`

and the setting related to swagger

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'JSON_EDITOR': True,
    'base_path': '/django/',
    'VALIDATOR_URL': None
    }
```

Note : it works correctly using `localhost:port/api`